# Send email notification when new post from post type is created

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a time trying to get this to work and I feel like I have tried everything from `transition_post_status`, to `wp_insert_post` and even `draft_to_pending` for my actions.

I'm trying to send an email to a user and the post author.  The user is set via ACF user object.  The problem I think, is that possibly the meta is not available or something because $author and $user are not objects so it's not finding them by the ID and grabbing their data.

Here is my function:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_volunteer_request_email', 10, 3 );
function send_volunteer_request_email( $new_status, $old_status, $post ){
  if ( 'volunteers' !== get_post_type( $post ) )
    return;

  if( wp_is_post_autosave( $post ) ) return;

  $user = get_field('user', $post);
  $user_data = get_userdata( $user );
  $the_event = get_field('event', $post);
  $event = get_post($the_event);
  $eventLink = get_permalink($event);
  $author = get_userdata( $event->post_author );

  if(get_post_status($post) == 'pending'){
    //Notify event author
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $subject = 'You have a new volunteer';
    $body = '<p>A member has volunteered to meet your need. Click <a href="' . $eventLink . '">here</a> to view and accept or decline!</p>';
    $body .= '<p>Thank you for being a valuable member<br><a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.goole.com</a><br>910-555-1234</p>';
    wp_mail( $author->user_email, $subject, $body, $headers );
  }
}
```

Here is an example of one of the errors:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'user_email' of non-object
```

And finally, you can see where these are set
[image]

Comment: Becasue you have a dependencies chain on the variables, you should check every step on your chain to see where it is failing, e.g. : `$the_event = get_field('event', $post);` ; `$event = get_post($the_event);` ;  `$author = get_userdata( $event->post_author );` . like this you can verify where the `ID` or another data is missing that results in a missing object.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code as below:

```
$user = get_field('user', $post->ID);
$user_data = get_userdata( $user );
$the_event = get_field('event', $post->ID);
$event = get_post($the_event);
```

The reason that you are getting the error is because you were passing post object to `get_field` function instead of post id.

Comment: @Derek In case you haven't yet been able to resolve this issue, have a look at my updated answer.